# Insert data into MySQL Database using javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made a very simple page using google maps API with several fields where users are going to put some data. It looks like following -

http://aiworker2.usask.ca/marker_field_db.html

What I want to do is store the data into MySQL database using javascript/Ajax. I have found several examples that has used Jquery. I'm very new to this javascript/Ajax/Jquery platform. Now my question is-

1. Is it possible to insert data into MySQL database without using JQuery?
2. Can anyone send any link of simple example or tutorial to deal with the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript runs on the client (in the browser).  Your MySQL database exists on a server.

In short, the client-side JavaScript cannot establish a **direct** connection to MySQL.  You need to make an AJAX request to the server which runs a script that interacts with MySQL.  The script can be written in any language that has a MySQL library.

Here's an example where an AJAX request is made, which calls a PHP script on the server, which, in turn, grabs data from a MySQL database and returns results back to the client:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to a MySQL database via JavaScript using ActivexObject. Example:

```
var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=mysite;Database=Northwind;User Id=MyId;Password=123aBc";
conn.open(connStr);
```

Comment: hey can you please tell me how to write insert query after connection will open. Thanks in Advances.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a GET request to a server script with AJAX:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to insert data into MySQL database without using JQuery?

Yes.
That said, jQuery helps you a lot dealing with Ajax (and cross-browser compatibility), so I would still consider it.

> Can anyone send any link of simple example or tutorial to deal with the issue?

Any Ajax tutorial will do it (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX). You just have to learn how to send data to the server side (as `POST` or `GET` request). Then it is just PHP and MySQL.