# How to store the retrieved HTML table values in the database?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Here i am retrieving the whole html table values using jquery.What I need is to store these retrieved values in the database table.Here is my code

```
$(function () {
     var message = $('#message');
     var table = $('#tbl');
     table.bind('click', function(){
         var values = '';
         var valArray = new Array();             
         var j = 0;
         var tr = $(this).find('tr');
         tr.each(function(){
             var i = 0;
             valArray[j] = new Array();
             var tds = $(this).find('td');
             $.each(tds, function (index, item) {
                 values = values + 'td' + (index + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + '<br/>';
                 valArray[j][i] = 'td' + (index + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + '<br/>';
                 i++;
             });
             j++;
         });
         message.html(values);
         //valArray is having the data organized in an bidimensional array style
     });                                    
 });
```

and

```
<table id="tbl" style="border: solid 1px black"> 
        <tr> 
            <td> 
                1 
            </td> 
            <td> 
                a 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td> 
                2 
            </td> 
            <td> 
                b 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
</table> 
    <br /> 
    <div id="message"> 
    </div>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you looking to store the entire table makup and all in the db and one big string or do you need to parse of specific values and store each value in a sep field?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it directly using jQuery...
you need to use AJAX request for this..

Here is the same question.. refer it..

[Insert data into MySQL Database using javascript/AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139532/insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-javascript-ajax)