# insert into data base by javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i have this code for get rss from other site

```
gfeedfetcher.prototype._displayresult=function(feeds){
    var rssoutput=(this.itemcontainer=="<li>")? "<ul>\n" : ""
    gfeedfetcher._sortarray(feeds, this.sortstring)
    for (var i=0; i<feeds.length; i++){
        var itemtitle="<a href=\"" + feeds[i].link + "\" target=\"" + this.linktarget + "\" class=\"titlefield\">" + feeds[i].title + "</a>"
        var itemlabel=/label/i.test(this.showoptions)? '<span class="labelfield">['+this.feeds[i].ddlabel+']</span>' : " "
        var itemdate=gfeedfetcher._formatdate(feeds[i].publishedDate, this.showoptions)
        var itemdescription=/description/i.test(this.showoptions)? "<br />"+feeds[i].content : /snippet/i.test(this.showoptions)? "<br />"+feeds[i].contentSnippet  : ""
        rssoutput+=this.itemcontainer + itemtitle + " " + itemlabel + " " + itemdate + "\n" + itemdescription + this.itemcontainer.replace("<", "</") + "\n\n"
    }
    rssoutput+=(this.itemcontainer=="<li>")? "</ul>" : ""
    this.feedcontainer.innerHTML=rssoutput
}
```

then i need to insert title and linke of the new on table on data base this cod by javascript

Comment: See this SO question, probably similar with what you want to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139532/insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-javascript-ajax

Comment: no no , i have var feeds[i].link , feeds[i].title  , i wont to make sql to insert it on data base

Comment: You haven't read the whole article and the answer portion of the link I gave you. You got a similar problem, trying to handle database data insertion with JS/jQuery/Ajax

Comment: Use jQuery + ajax, with a php database handler in the back-end called by the ajax request.

Comment: See example in my answer below.

Comment: So, user1433402, what PHP code do you have so far, to insert the data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

Example of an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", // or GET
  url: "databasehandler.php",
  data: { feedtitle: "Some Title", feedlink: "Some URL" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

--

**databasehandler.php**

```
<?php

     print_r($_POST);

     // 
     // Do your database handles here.
     // Connect, Query, then return success/failure status

?>
```